# Eclipse Kepler Freezes when copying

Tags: eclipse

I have an Eclipse Kepler IDE where ADT Plugins, CDT plugis, Android NDK and Java is installed. It is sort of my lifeline IDE at work. Without this my whole work will come to a standstill. I have this IDE installed on a Vbox Ubuntu  machine and have been using it for the past one year(ever since the glorious JUNO version days!). About 2 months ago, my IDE was veyr slow so I upgraded it from Juno to Kepler expecting better performance. I must admit it was not any at all. Also, on my VBox, the IDE froze a couple of times whenever I plugged in a USB in my Virtual Box. I assumed it must be some bug with the USB and just left it. Today, all of a sudden (this is the 5th time I have rebooted my virtual image) whenever I tried to copy a piece of code in my IDE, the whole IDE freezes. Only a kill -9 pid number command came to rescue after that. What should I do? Please suggest!!

thanks a lot.

Comment: How will you find a pin in hay stack? There will be lots of plugins installed in eclipse. How will you check which one is causing the issue. Better than that get a fresh eclipse copy with minimal plugins

Answer (score 1):

First, you should configure the Java VM to create a thread dump when Eclipse hangs. Eclipse doesn't just hang for the fun of it; something is wrong but since there is a deadlock, Eclipse can't tell you anymore. Read up on [debugging deadlocks](http://www.thebinaryidiot.com/archives/2011/11/01/debugging-java-deadlocks-with-visualvm/).

The next step when Eclipse is acting up is always to clean the `.metadata` folder since a crash sometimes corrupts important files in there. [See this blog post](http://blog.pdark.de/2011/09/02/restoring-a-corrupted-workspace-in-eclipse/).

If that also doesn't help, you can try to reinstall Eclipse. Install the plugins one after the other, noting down what you do until you find the one which breaks the others.